# Deploy.js script is inifinite, does not show any errors

Tags: solidity, solc, console

This is the deploy.js file:

```
        const assert = require('assert'); 
        const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider'); 
        const Web3 = require('web3'); 
        const cF = require('./Build/CampaignFact.json');

        const provider = new HDWalletProvider( 
            /*account seed phrase*/,    
            'rinkeby.infura.io/account_Address' 
         ); 
        const web3 = new Web3(provider);

            const deploy = async () => {    
                const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

                console.log('Attemping to deploy from account', accounts[0]);

                const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(cF.interface))        
                               .deploy({ data: '0x'+ cF.bytecode })         
                               .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000' });

                console.log('Contract deployed to: ', result.options.address);
            }; 
        deploy();
```

CampaignFact.json and Campaign.json are the compiled files of my contract. 
The Campiagn.sol file is described below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract CampaignFact {
    address[] public deployedCampaigns;

function createCampaign(uint min) public {
    address newC = new Campaign(min, msg.sender);
    deployedCampaigns.push(newC);
}

function getDeployedCampaigns() public view returns (address[] memory) {
    return deployedCampaigns;
  }
}
contract Campaign {

struct Request {
    string description;
    uint value;
    address recipient;
    bool complete;
    uint approvalCount;
    mapping (address => bool) approvals;
}

Request[] public requests;
address public manager;
uint public minimumContribution;
mapping (address => bool) public approvers;
uint public approversCount;

modifier restrict() {
    require(msg.sender == manager);
    _;
}

constructor(uint min, address creator) public {
    manager = creator;
    minimumContribution = min;
}

function contribute() public payable {
    require(msg.value > minimumContribution, "Error: You do not have enough money. You are poor.");
    approvers[msg.sender] = true;
    approversCount++;
}

function createRequest(string memory desc, uint val, address rec) public restrict {
    //make sure that this person has donated earlier
    require(approvers[msg.sender]);

    Request memory newReq = Request({
        description: desc,
        value: val,
        recipient: rec,
        complete: false,
        approvalCount: 0
    });

    requests.push(newReq);
}

function approveRequest(uint index) public {
    Request storage r = requests[index];

    //make sure person has donated before he starts to vote
    require(approvers[msg.sender]);

    //make sure person has not voted before
    require(!r.approvals[msg.sender]);

    r.approvals[msg.sender] = true;
    r.approvalCount++;
}

function finalizeRequest(uint index) public restrict {

    Request storage r = requests[index];

    require(r.approvalCount > (approversCount / 2) );
    require(!r.complete);       

    r.recipient.transfer(r.value);
    r.complete = true;
  }
}
```

I don't know but the script gets working till a point comes where I need to exit the command prompt. Please help me out here.

I'll also link the compile.js file that compiles 2 contracts(Campaign and CampaignFact) together. I guess that's where the error would be.

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const solc = require('solc');

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'Build');
fs.removeSync(buildPath); //deletes the build folder

const contractPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Campaign.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(contractPath, 'utf-8');
const output = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts;

fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath); //checks if exists; if doesn't, create one

for(let contract in output) {
    fs.outputJsonSync(
        path.resolve(buildPath,contract.replace(':','') +  '.json'), 
        output[contract]
    );
}
```

The file structure is:

> Ethereum
>
> - Build
>
>   - Campaign.json
>   - CampaignFact.json
> - Contracts
>
>   - Campaign.sol
> - compile.js
> - deploy.js

**Note: The contract gets deployed, but that address does not show up when I use it in my webpage. I wrote this because the deploy script is infinite.**

Bear with me, please! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are doing the Udemy course of Stephen Grider cause I did the same couple months ago and it seems similar.

According to my own project, there are a couple of missing things on your compile.js. Probably cause you are still in an early state of the course. Although, I will leave my build here and you try it out and make some comparison. I made some comments in hope to make you understand it better. Good luck.

```
const path = require("path"); //nodejs ’path’ module
const solc = require("solc"); //solidity compiler module
const fs = require("fs-extra"); //file system module

// Feth path of build
const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "build");
const contractspath = path.resolve(__dirname, "contracts");

// Removes folder build and every file in it
fs.removeSync(buildPath);

// Fetch all Contract files in Contracts folder
const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(contractspath);

// Gets ABI of all contracts into variable input
const input = fileNames.reduce(
  (input, fileName) => {
    const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "contracts", fileName);
    const source = fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf8");
    return { sources: { ...input.sources, [fileName]: source } };
  },
  { sources: {} }
);

// Compile all contracts
const output = solc.compile(input, 1).contracts;

// Re-Create build folder for output files from each contract
fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);

// Output contains all objects from all contracts
// Write the contents of each to different files
for (let contract in output) {
  fs.outputJsonSync(
    path.resolve(buildPath, contract.split(":")[1] + ".json"),
    output[contract]
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, I am on that video series. It's just that the code goes on and on. Otherwise, it works really fine.